# MEAN.JS: Server username security

Tags: node.js, security, meanjs

Using [MEAN.JS](http://meanjs.org/) is possible to bring a Server Error changing this:

```
http://localhost:3000/#!/
```

To:

```
http://localhost:3000/%C0#!/
```

> Error: Bad Request
>       at SendStream.error (/home/**username**/Project/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:239:16)
>       at SendStream.pipe (/home/**username**/Project/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:411:32)
>       at serveStatic (/home/**username**/Project/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:110:12)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/**username**/Project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/home/**username**/Project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:269:13)
>       at /home/**username**/Project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:236:9
>       at Function.proto.process_params (/home/**username**/Project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:311:12)
>       at /home/**username**/Project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:227:12
>       at Function.match_layer (/home/ec2-user/Project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:294:3)
>       at next (/home/**username**/Project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:188:10)

We can see the **username of the server** and this is dangerous...

Any suggestion to solve this bug?

Comment: The solution is to run your production server from a different folder.

Comment: Enable custom errors instead of showing the stack trace.

Comment: How can I make a custom error in Mean.JS? what file is it? Thank you !

Comment: Okey, sorry for the fast ask. app/views/500.server.view.html is the file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy. Only need to modify the message of file `app/views/500.server.view.html`